# Uploading image to webserver on windows phone using C#

Tags: c#, windows, file-upload, ftp, windows-phone

How can i have the app user choose a picture from their photo album and how do i upload the picture to my web server? I know how to use Phone Task. I just need to know how i can upload the photo to my web server. Is there a tutorial online?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what web server you have and what technologies it use.
If your server is RESTful you need to use HttpWebRequest or HttpClient with POST method, code image to base64 string add it to json or xml object, put it in request body and send to server. 
You gave question without any details so I can't help you with code.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the image to base64 and posting the base64 string to your webpage should work.

Comment: I dont know how to do that.I need to use the URL of the image file as the user's profile picture. Will it work with this method?

Comment: You need a PHP backend which handles the upload!
There are a few articles/posts on converting an image to base64 and a lot of posts on the topic "POST webrequest". These should help!